# Why I can't send a post method in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I have this method to post the value to the "/store/add_to_cart"

```
<form action = "/store/add_to_cart" method="post">
<% for product in @products -%>
<div class   = "entry">
<%= product.title %>
<%= product.price %>
<p>
</div>
<% end %>
<%= select( "payment", "id", { "Visa" => "1", "Mastercard" => "2"}) %>
<%= submit_tag 'Make Order' %>
</form>
```

In the /store/add_to_cart.html.erb, I created :

```
<%= params.length %>
<% for i in params%>
<%=i%>
<br/>

<% end %>
```

But I get this error:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in StoreController#add_to_cart

What's happen? but after I change it to the get method, I can get all the params, wt's happen?

Comment: it relates to routes.rb? I can submit the form in "get" method within prompting any error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not using rails `form_for` helper to generate the `<form>` HTML markup, what this method does in addition is to add a hidden input field that is used to prevent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks.

You have three options:

1. Use the [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), form_tag... helper
2. Include the [hidden](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) [input](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#M000512) yourself
3. [Disable](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/9/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-better-cross-site-request-forging-prevention) [the](http://m.onkey.org/2007/9/28/csrf-protection-for-your-existing-rails-application) [CSRF](http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/08/13/using-text_field_with_auto_complete-and-form_authenticity_token/) support

Comment: Something like:

<% form_for controller => 'store', :action => add_to_cart, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
...
<% end %>

but that's just not DRY enough, I would recommend that you do a more RESTful design, checkout: http://nubyonrails.com/articles/peepcode-rest-basics, http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/08/01/whats-new-in-edge-rails-simply-restful-support-and-how-to-use-it, http://www.b-simple.de/download/restful_rails_en.pdf (PDF)